# capture form data with plain js and store in reusable variable

Tags: javascript

Say, I have a simple form:

*ie.* Just for example, although will be a lot larger.

```
<form action="">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I would like to make it so every time a user '*submits*' the form, rather then post it with *php*. I would like to use vanilla javascript to take the form contents that were inserted by the user, and store all content in a javascript variable with the naming convention similar to:

```
var = submission1
var = submission2
var = submission3
```

..and it would have all user submitted form field contents. Later down the line I could grab the form field contents via variable. I want to accomplish this with pure vanilla js. No php nor js libraries, and I don't want to alter the mark-up either.

Comment: use a submit handler to serialize the form and return false to prevent submitting to the server.

Comment: It seems you are looking for an array of submission objects. Never use indexed variables.

Comment: Yes, Bingo @Bergi